# $H_1(A\cap B)\to H_1B$ is 1-1 implies $H_1A\to H_1(A\cup B)$ is 1-1

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A,B$ be two open set of a topological space, $H_1(A\cap B)\to H_1B$ is 1-1 implies $H_1A\to H_1(A\cup B)$ is 1-1, where the homomorphisms is induced by inclusion.

I feel that using the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence is the key to this question since

$$H_1(A\cap B)\to H_1A\times H_1B\to H_1(A\cup B)$$

is an exact sequence, where the first homomorphism takes $[\gamma]_{A\cap B}\mapsto([\gamma]_A,-[\gamma]_B)$ and the second homomorphism takes $([\gamma]_A,[\delta]_B)\mapsto[\gamma+\delta]_{A\cup B}$. But how should I use these facts to prove the claim?

Comment: Think about the restriction of the second map to $H_1(A) \times \{0\}$.